# Parent is null in ListView delegate after upgrade to Qt 5.15

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

A `ListView` with a most simple delegate produces lots of warnings `"21:35:31.911 warning T#16084047 unknown - qrc:/main.qml:15: TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of null"` if trying to set it's delegate `anchors` property and scrolling the list (which makes delegates to be destroyed/created). It was not the case in Qt 5.12 or 5.9.

File `main.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: cppModel

        delegate: Rectangle {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            height: 50

            Text { text: model.itemName }
        }
    }
}
```

File `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <iostream>

void myMessageHandler(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg) {
    QString logLine = qFormatLogMessage(type, context, msg);
    std::cout << logLine.toStdString() << std::endl;
}

class CppModel: public QAbstractListModel {
    // QAbstractItemModel interface
public:
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override { return 100; }
    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override {
        if (role == (Qt::DisplayRole + 1)) {
            return QString("Element %1").arg(index.row());
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override {
        return {{(Qt::DisplayRole+1), "itemName"}};
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qSetMessagePattern("%{time hh:mm:ss.zzz} %{type} T#%{threadid} %{function} - %{message}");
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageHandler);

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    CppModel cppModel;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppModel", &cppModel);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

[Link to full source code](https://gist.github.com/ribtoks/62b68d2b1c219770b683e96cebc75d0f)

What I'm doing wrong and how to correctly set `anchors` for the delegate element?

Comment: Um why are you using the `anchors` like this? To me it seems like a `width: parent.width` would be better. Also giving the `ListView` an `id` and reference it by it instead of `parent`

Comment: @Megued if you read the question again, you will see that the problem is that `parent` is `null`, not the `parent.left` is `null`. Also delegate's parent is `contentItem`, not the `ListView` itself so referencing it by ID is not correct.

Comment: I know what the error says, that's why I suggested to use `ListView`, for the reference as the `contentItem` obviously doesn't exists, and since ListView is the parent of it, I don't see any issue in using it for the same result, just with no errors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the result of a behaviour change in Qt 5.15. The first issue was reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81976), with a more detailed summary [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82989). The [new documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#example-usage) says:

> Delegates are instantiated as needed and may be destroyed at any time.
> As such, state should never be stored in a delegate. Delegates are
> usually parented to ListView's contentItem, but typically depending on
> whether it's visible in the view or not, the parent can change, and
> sometimes be null. Because of that, binding to the parent's properties
> from within the delegate is not recommended. If you want the delegate
> to fill out the width of the ListView, consider using one of the
> following approaches instead:
>
> ```
> ListView {
>     id: listView
>     // ...
>
>     delegate: Item {
>         // Incorrect.
>         width: parent.width
>
>         // Correct.
>         width: listView.width
>         width: ListView.view.width
>         // ...
>     }
> }
> ```

So, you can either:

1. Give the `ListView` an `id` and use it in the binding instead of `parent`.
2. Use the attached property (`ListView.view`) to access the view.
3. Check for null (`anchors.left: parent ? parent.left : undefined`).

Options 1 and 2 will result in cleaner code.

Option 1 results in one less `QObject` being created (each attached object is a `QObject`) but ties the delegate to that particular view.

Option 2 is better for delegates that are standalone components that will be reused with other `ListView`s.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation!

Comment: 1st does not work - returns error: `Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.`

Comment: 3rd expression also wrong: `anchors.left` could not be `null`. Correct one: `anchors { left: parent ? parent.left : undefined; right: parent ? parent.right : undefined }`

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich If you were anchoring to the parent, you'll now need to change that binding to refer to `listView.contentItem`, since that's the parent, not the view itself.

Comment: @Mitch the whole point here is that the item may not have a parent sometimes. Anchoring will not work.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb, not sure why you're telling me that it may not have a parent when my answer already stated that. I don't appreciate your tone. Also, anchoring does work.

Comment: @Mitch anchoring is only allowed to the parent or a sibling. So the anchoring to content item does not work, during the time that the item has no acestors. I didn't intend to sound inappropriate. Just wanted to point out the issue in the logic.

Comment: Therefore, it should be smth like `anchors.left: parent ? ListView.view.contentItem : undefined` . There's also `anchors.left: parent?.left` for kind of "cleaner"/shorter code, though requires modern Qt version.